# How to send notifications from android to RPi?

Tags: pi-2, connection, android

I have a project in my college, In that i need to push arrived notifications from android phone to RPi and i want to display those in the raspberry pi screen. How can i do that please somebody help....

Comment: Welcome to the RPi flavored corner of StackExchange, Justin. Have you done any research on this topic on your own? Have any idea what kind of technology stack you'll be using? Your question is far too broad for this format, and doesn't really have anything to do with the RPi anyway. It's a basic networking/programming problem.

Comment: Since you said this is a college project, have you considered asking your Professor/Instructor or TA?

Answer (score 2):

From a quick Google search I found the "LinConnect" project. It mirrors all Android notifications and sends them to a Linux server, thus it should be compatible with the Raspberry Pi. It uses Python.

[Google Play Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.willhauck.linconnectclient&hl=en)

[Server software on GitHub](https://github.com/hauckwill/linconnect-server)